# Change all table cell colours when my reset button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a javascript problem. What I am trying to do is set the colour of every cell in a table to a chosen colour once a reset button has been clicked.

This is what I have so far:

```
function resetColour(objName)
{  
    var arr = new Array();
    arr = document.getElementsByName(objName);

    alert("total objects with name \"free\" = \n" + arr.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr(i).style.backgroundColor = "#FAF4E3";
    }
}
```

The end of my html looks like this:

```
                <tr>
                    <td onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center>17:00 - 18:00</center></td>
                    <td onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon17"></center></td>
                    <td onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="tue17"></center></td>
                    <td onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="wed17"></center></td>
                    <td onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="thu17"></center></td>
                    <td onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="fri17"></center></td>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="resetColour('free')">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

What am I doing wrong that is making this not work?

EDIT: This piece of javascrip might be messing things up for me. How can I edit this so that it will change the colour of the whole td?

```
function tdOnclick(td) {
    for(var i = 0; i < td.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if(td.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
            if(td.childNodes[i].nodeName == "INPUT") {
                if(td.childNodes[i].checked) {
                    td.childNodes[i].checked = false;
                    td.style.backgroundColor = "#FAF4E3";
                } else {
                    td.childNodes[i].checked = true;
                    td.style.backgroundColor = "#E1E1E1";
                    input.style.backgroundColor = "#E1E1E1";
                }
            } else {
                tdOnclick(td.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[so you want the `<td>`'s to change color based on the name you pass?](http://jsfiddle.net/T99eW/1/) (not the `<input>`, not the `<center>`)

```
function resetColour(objName){  

    //get element by name (as requested by post)
    var arr = document.getElementsByName(objName);

    //store length in variable
    //some say accessing .length in a loop condition adds overhead 
    var arrLen = arr.length;

    //loop through all found elements    
    for(var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++){

        //InputElement.CenterTag.TdElement.style.backgroundColor = foo
        arr[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
    }
}

function tdOnclick(obj){
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
}
```

you might wanna avoid using `<center>`, besides that it's deprecated, it's the cause of the additional `.parentNode` in the code (totally unnecessary). use CSS to center content instead.

Comment: Thanks, the only reason that center is there is because another guy I'm working with made all the code, I'm just in charge of CSS and javascript. I'll try out your solution now.

Comment: Ok, I have your piece of code working and it does as I ask. However, I think some javascript I am already using is affecting it.

I'll put it in the OP so you can check it out.

Comment: I have edited the OP to show the javascript that may be colouring the wrong elements.

Comment: I got rid of the center tags and it works perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry to annoy you @Joseph but I have one more small problem. When I go to tick my checkbox, it only checks if I tick anywhere in the cell APART from the actual checkbox. It's pretty bizarre. The checkbox highlights and everything but won't allow me to tick.

Answer (score 0):

try

document.getElementsByTagName('td').style.backgroundColor="#FAF4E3";

Comment: Yes I just tried now. It works great but I think some of my other javascript code is messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

You that code was basically trying to set the background colour of the input type itself as opposed to the td that surrounds the checkboxes. check box styles are often determined by the OS.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="a"onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center>17:00 - 18:00</center></td>
    <td class="a" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon17"></center></td>
    <td class="a" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="tue17"></center></td>
    <td class="a" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="wed17"></center></td>
    <td class="a" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="thu17"></center></td>
    <td class="a" onclick="tdOnclick(this)"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="fri17"></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="resetColour()">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

<script>
function resetColour(objName)
{
    $('.a').each(function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#000000');

    });
}
</script>
```

It's simple with jQuery:

```
$('.a').each(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#000000');
});
```

Comment: you do notice that the OP didn't tag jQuery right? meaning he may not need jQuery.